# PyQT with MVC and Signals/Slots

Tags: model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Can one implement signals/slots inside of an MVC architecture? Do signals/slots extend beyond their the "main" class? I mean, usually you have a MainUI that inherits from the UI class (that contains your view, or all your buttons and stuff). But if you have other classes that don't inherit from this ui (but still inherit from Qt), can they all see the same slots/signals?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and seems far too broad. What *specific* problems are you trying to solve? Qt already includes a [Model/View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) - are you sure you've researched everything properly?

Comment: Yes, they certainly can. Events are sent throughout the entire app.